# Correct use of bound/bounded

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, mathematics

I am not sure how to correctly use the word ***bound*** in this context:

> All partial sums of two given sequences are bounded by a positive constant.
>
> All partial sums of two given sequences are bound by a positive constant.

Comment: 'Bounded' has a different meaning to 'bound'. The former has to do with boundary, indicating the limits of something. 'Bound' is the past tense of 'bind'. I am not sure if this helps, but you may need a dictionary of mathematical terms.

Comment: Yes, It seems that it is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Verb: *[bind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bind#Verb)*
Past: *[bound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bound#Verb)*
Noun: a *[binding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binding#Noun)* (in some senses)
Used in various senses in [physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding#Physical_sciences) and [computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding#Computing) but not in mathematics.

Verb: *[bound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bound#Verb_2)*
Past: *[bounded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bounded#Verb)*
Noun: a *[bound](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bound#Noun)*
Used in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds) and [computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking) to denote a range or finite area in which a value must be.

The sentence in your question is about a bound, therefore the past participle is *bounded*.

> All partial sums of two given sequences are **bounded** by a positive constant.
>   There is a **bound** on the partial sums of two given sequences.

Answer (score 5):

The difficulty you are facing is that there are two separate verbs in play here.

The verb **[bind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bind)** means

> Tie or fasten (something) tightly

Its past tense and past participle is **bound**

The verb **[bound](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bound#bound-2)** (present tense) means

> Form the boundary of; enclose

or

> Place within certain limits; restrict

[Bound](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/bound) can also mean

> to move with a leap or series of leaps

In each of these cases, the past and past participle form of **bound** is **bounded**.

In the example given by the OP, it seems that the meaning is *to place within limits* (rather than *to tie to*). The verb would then be **bound** and the past participle is **bounded**. In the construction given, **bounded** is correct and *bound* is not.

Answer (score 3):

The expression "to be bounded" meaning being limited or having a border is registered in English dictionaries.